# Is the halfwidth ideographic comma (､) (U+FF64) ever used in Chinese punctuation?

Tags: punctuation

My digital version of《现代汉语规范词典》seems to be using halfwidth ideographic commas, `､` (U+FF64).

Here's their definition for **巾**:

> 名 用来擦､包或盖东西的小块织物

It looks like a poor attempt at a fullwidth ideographic comma (顿号) and seems to be missing any sort of space what-so-ever after the punctuation mark.

Is there ever usage of the halfwidth ideographic comma in Chinese punctuation? (Add your own spaces?)

Comment: A wild guess is that they made an exception in the case of a several hundred pages long dictionary where they decided it would be worth the cumulative space savings, and the digital edition just kept this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mainstream pinyin input methods mainly use full-width '、' character.  And under most formal situations, full-width '、' is required to keep consistency with other full-width punctuation markers (for example: '。', '，', '！').

Answer (score 2):

I’d say no. All regular Chinese punctuation marks are full-width. There shouldn't be any spaces before or after punctuation marks when you are typesetting Chinese.

When people input Chinese, all Chinese characters and punctuation marks are typed under the full-width mode, while numbers, letters, and other symbols should be typed under the half-width mode. “、” (顿号) is no exception.