How to type U+3001 IDEOGRAPHIC COMMA on a chromebook?
Sure, I can type

U+3002 IDEOGRAPHIC FULL STOP
U+FF0C FULLWIDTH COMMA

with no problem in the Chromebook's Text app,
using the ChromeOS Chinese input methods.
But how could there be no way to type

U+3001 IDEOGRAPHIC COMMA ?

Yes, it is needed a lot,
https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/29270/214

I use "" in Google Pinyin; usually they're fairly consistent.

I’m not familiar with your specific environment. I wonder what happens if you press "" with the Chinese input methods. Usually pressing "" in full width mode will get you a "、".

Just like @Becky 李蓓 says, \ is 、 in full width mode
Some other punctuation input methods that are not easy to discover:



In half width mode
In full width mode




^
……


_
——


< >
《 》


[ ]
【 】


\
、


`
·




In Linux, press ctrl + shift + u together and then release them
Enter 3001
Press space and you should see as below
、
3002
。
ff0c
，
Not sure how to do this in Windows, never use Win.

Nice to always have this "hard way" backup method!

Use "\" in Google Pinyin, like @Becky 李蓓 discovered. (But how did they know?)

Because Chinese input punctuation like this
